# How to show value on tkinter label when calibration work going on

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on application where I had four buttons named **CAL**,**ENT**,**INC**,**DEC**.
And when I pressed **CAL** button range_H value displayed on tkinter label and after that I am adjusting the value through **INC** and **DEC** button and after that by pressing **ENT** button I saved that value on .txt file.

My issue is when I changing the values through **INC** and **DEC** button ,the value isn't updating on tkinter Label .

So I tried with `root.after(100,cal)`.So values updated on tkinter label but It is not destroyed after pressing **ENT** button.

I am quite new to both Python and tkinter .So I may be made some silly mistake to do like this.

Complete code

```
import os
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x240")
range_High = tk.StringVar()
range_H = 32767

file=open("D:\data/file_log.txt","w")
if os.stat("D:\data/file_log.txt").st_size==0:
    file.write("rangeHigh,\n")
file.write(str(range_H))
file.flush()

def cal():
    global range_High
    root.rangeLabel = tk.Label(root, textvariable=range_High)
    root.rangeLabel.grid(row=0)
    range_High.set(range_H)
 #   root.after(100,cal)

def enter():
    global range_High
    file=open("D:\data/file_log.txt","w")
    if os.stat("D:\data/file_log.txt").st_size==0:
       file.write("rangeHigh,\n")
    file.write(str(range_H))
    file.flush()
    root.rangeLabel.destroy()
def inc():
    global range_H
    range_H = range_H + 1
def dec():
    global range_H
    range_H = range_H - 1
root.Bt1=tk.Button(root,text="cal",bg="red",command=cal)
root.Bt1.pack()
root.Bt1.place(x=200,y=100)
root.Bt2=tk.Button(root,text="ent",bg="red",command=enter)
root.Bt2.pack()
root.Bt2.place(x=200,y=130)
root.Bt3=tk.Button(root,text="inc",bg="red",fg="white",command=inc)
root.Bt3.pack()
root.Bt3.place(x=200,y=160)
root.Bt4=tk.Button(root,text="dec",bg="red",fg="white",command=dec)
root.Bt4.pack()
root.Bt4.place(x=200,y=190)


#root.after(100,cal)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the variable range_High.set(range_H) in the inc and dec function to update in the screen.

Please change the file paths i have changed it to match mine.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x240")
range_High = tk.StringVar()
range_H = 32767

file=open(r"C:\Users\vignesh.rajendran\Pythonpractice\Stackoverflow\Tkinter/file_log.txt","w")
if os.stat(r"C:\Users\vignesh.rajendran\Pythonpractice\Stackoverflow\Tkinter/file_log.txt").st_size==0:
    file.write("rangeHigh,\n")
file.write(str(range_H))
file.flush()

def cal():
    global range_High
    root.rangeLabel = tk.Label(root, textvariable=range_High)
    root.rangeLabel.grid(row=0)
    range_High.set(range_H)
 #   root.after(100,cal)

def enter():
    global range_High
    file=open(r"C:\Users\vignesh.rajendran\Pythonpractice\Stackoverflow\Tkinter/file_log.txt","w")
    if os.stat(r"C:\Users\vignesh.rajendran\Pythonpractice\Stackoverflow\Tkinter/file_log.txt").st_size==0:
       file.write("rangeHigh,\n")
    file.write(str(range_H))
    file.flush()
    root.rangeLabel.destroy()
def inc():
    global range_H
    range_H = range_H + 1
    range_High.set(range_H)

def dec():
    global range_H
    range_H = range_H - 1
    range_High.set(range_H)
    
root.Bt1=tk.Button(root,text="cal",bg="red",command=cal)
root.Bt1.pack()
root.Bt1.place(x=200,y=100)
root.Bt2=tk.Button(root,text="ent",bg="red",command=enter)
root.Bt2.pack()
root.Bt2.place(x=200,y=130)
root.Bt3=tk.Button(root,text="inc",bg="red",fg="white",command=inc)
root.Bt3.pack()
root.Bt3.place(x=200,y=160)
root.Bt4=tk.Button(root,text="dec",bg="red",fg="white",command=dec)
root.Bt4.pack()
root.Bt4.place(x=200,y=190)


#root.after(100,cal)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,that's what I want.

Comment: ,Can you help me little more .Actually this application have three variable that is `range_H`, `offset` and `full_scale` .I need to adjust three variable values and show them in same label in the time of calibration. For that I know I need fetch the base address but I am in little bit of confusion. Thanks a lot in advance